# Jasmine Tdd first try

Tags: javascript, jasmine, tdd

I am writing a program to test for different triangle types and I am stuck. This is what I have for my testing:

(left comments in for thought process).

app-spec.js

```
describe("Answer", function () {
    var equilateral;
    var sideA;
    var sideB;
    var sideC;
    it("Should return equilateral when all sides are equal", function () {
        expect(whichTriangle(sideA, sideB, sideC).toEqual(sideA, sideB, sideC));
        // expect (sideA).tobe(sideB);
        // expect (sideB).tobe(sideC);
        // expect (sideC).tobe(sideA);
        // !expect (sideA, sideB, sideC).tobe(undefined);
    });
    it("Should return isosceles when 2 sides are equal", function () {
        // let sideD: number;
        // let sideE: number;
        // let sideF: number;
        expect(sideA).tobe((sideB));
        expect(sideB).tobe((sideC));
        !expect(sideA, sideB, sideC).toEqual(sideA, sideB, sideC);
    });
    it("Should return scalene when no sides are equal", function () {
        // let sideG: number;
        // let sideH: number;
        // let sideI: number;
        !expect(sideA).tobe(sideB);
        !expect(sideB).tobe(sideC);
        !expect(sideC).tobe(sideA);
    });
});
describe("Isosceles triangle", function () {
    var isosceles;
});
```

This is what I have for my app.js file:

app.js

```
function whichTriangle(sideA, sideB, sideC) {
    // let side1 = document.getElementById('sideA').value();
    // let side2 = document.getElementById('sideB').value();
    // let side3 = document.getElementById('sideC').value();
    if (side1 === side2 && side3) {
        console.log("triangle is Equilateral");
    }
    else if (side1 === side2 && side1 != side3) {
        console.log("triangle is an isosceles");
    }
    else if (side1 != side2 && side1 != side3 && side2 != side3) {
        console.log('triangle is a scalene');
    }
    else if (side1 === null || side1 === undefined ||
        side2 === null || side2 === undefined ||
        side3 === null || side3 === undefined) {
        console.log('You must enter a number for all 3 sides');
    }
    else {
        console.log('You got me I don\'t know what this shape is. Maybe a rectangle?');
    }
}
equalSides(1, 1, 1);
```

This is what I am getting when I run the app:

Jasmine Spec Runner

```
3 specs, 3 failures
Spec List | Failures
Answer Should return equilateral when all sides are equal
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at equalSides (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/src/app.js:2:49)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/spec/app-spec.js:7:16)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3898:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3887:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3872:10)
    at Spec.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:816:35)
    at Spec.execute (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:473:10)
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:4975:37)
    at attemptAsync (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3945:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3884:9)
Answer Should return isosceles when 2 sides are equal
TypeError: expect(...).tobe is not a function
TypeError: expect(...).tobe is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/spec/app-spec.js:17:23)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3898:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3887:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3872:10)
    at Spec.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:816:35)
    at Spec.execute (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:473:10)
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:4975:37)
    at attemptAsync (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3945:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3884:9)
    at http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3924:18
Answer Should return scalene when no sides are equal
TypeError: expect(...).tobe is not a function
TypeError: expect(...).tobe is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/spec/app-spec.js:25:24)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3898:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3887:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3872:10)
    at Spec.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:816:35)
    at Spec.execute (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:473:10)
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:4975:37)
    at attemptAsync (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3945:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3884:9)
    at http://localhost:63342/greater%20sum%20test/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js:3924:18
```

Of course I know I am doing something wrong but any nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciated and criticism is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be `toBe` not `tobe`. I also noticed you are trying to say `not` by using `!` which doesn't work. You need to do `expect(something).not.toBe(somethingElse)`

Looks like you already know why you had the first 2 errors (the document selectors).

These are the reasons why your code throws errors. Though your unit tests and your function to be tested need to be rethought carefully. Your units are describing that the return value of the function should be a string describing the triangle. Your function however does not return a string, it prints to console. It'd be better if your function returned 'Equilateral', 'Isosceles' or 'Scalene'.

```
function whichTriangle(sideA, sideB, sideC) {
    // let side1 = document.getElementById('sideA').value();
    // let side2 = document.getElementById('sideB').value();
    // let side3 = document.getElementById('sideC').value();
    if (side1 === side2 && side1 === side3) {
        console.log("triangle is Equilateral");
        return 'Equilateral';
    }
    else if (side1 === side2 && side1 != side3) {
        console.log("triangle is an isosceles");
        return 'Isosceles';
    }
    else if (side1 != side2 && side1 != side3 && side2 != side3) {
        console.log('triangle is a scalene');
        return 'Scalene';
    }
    else if (side1 === null || side1 === undefined ||
        side2 === null || side2 === undefined ||
        side3 === null || side3 === undefined) {
        console.log('You must enter a number for all 3 sides');
    }
    else {
        console.log('You got me I don\'t know what this shape is. Maybe a rectangle?');
    }
    throw new Error('Not a triangle');
}
```

Each test should try out the correct return value of your function so you'd have:

```
it("Should return equilateral when all sides are equal", function () {
    expect(whichTriangle(1, 1, 1)).toBe('Equilateral');
});
it("Should return isosceles when 2 sides are equal", function () {
    expect(whichTriangle(1, 2, 1)).toBe('Isosceles');
});
it("Should return scalene when no sides are equal", function () {
    expect(whichTriangle(1, 2, 3)).toBe('Scalene');
});
```

However, there's still a bug inside your function, notice that:

```
side1 === side2 && side3
```

Doesn't mean all 3 sides are equal. It should be:

```
side1 === side2 && side1 === side3 //or side2 === side3
```

This is why you also make other tests!

```
it("Should not return equilateral when all sides are not equal", function () {
    expect(whichTriangle(1, 1, 2)).not.toBe('Equilateral');
    expect(whichTriangle(2, 1, 2)).not.toBe('Equilateral');
    expect(whichTriangle(2, 3, 2)).not.toBe('Equilateral');
});
it("Should not return isosceles when 3 sides are equal or none are equal", function () {
    expect(whichTriangle(2, 2, 2)).not.toBe('Isosceles');
    expect(whichTriangle(3, 2, 1)).not.toBe('Isosceles');
});
it("Should not return scalene there's at least one side equal", function () {
    expect(whichTriangle(1, 1, 2)).not.toBe('Scalene');
    expect(whichTriangle(1, 2, 1)).not.toBe('Scalene');
    expect(whichTriangle(2, 1, 1)).not.toBe('Scalene');
    expect(whichTriangle(2, 2, 2)).not.toBe('Scalene');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was using the ! and the reason for it was my IDE (webStorm) changed it to the ! when I typed _.not.toBe_ so I thought maybe it was something new I didn't know about and left it as such. I will make the changes and keep trying. Thank you again.

Comment: @PerryCraft, I added some `not` examples

Comment: Wow this is excellent and well writen thank you man so much. Probably the best explained answer I have ever gotten back. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see is that line:

```
expect(whichTriangle(sideA, sideB, sideC).toEqual(sideA, sideB, sideC));
```

should looks like that:

```
expect(whichTriangle(sideA, sideB, sideC)).toEqual(sideA, sideB, sideC);
```

Next one, function whichTriangle always return undefined so you test looks like that:
expect(undefined).toEqual(something).

For example when you want test if functions returns proper value you can do this like this:

```
const foo = function() {
  return 10;
}

it('should return 10', function() {
  expect(foo()).toEqual(10);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for that _expect_ change will do that and continue to chug along. I should have asked a day ago but I wanted to struggle to dig it into my brain.